# CSS for aligning select box text inconsistent across operating systems

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I noticed some cross platform compatibility issues when trying to set left padding on a select box. On non-mac google chrome, there seems to be a non breaking space or something added, which adds about 4 pixels. The padding is correct on both browsers, it's just the actual element that's affected.

The HTML is as follows:

```
    <select id="category" name="search_cat" data-default="All Categories">
        <option value="1">Ell Categories</option>
        <?php foreach ($data as $id => $d) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $id ?>">
            <?= $d ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

CSS:

```
.select-wrapper select {
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-position: 128px;
    background: url(../../i/arrow.png) no-repeat right center;
    border: 0;
    cursor: default;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here it is on Chrome on Linux (Displays this way on windows too)

[image: Chrome on linux]

Here it is on Chrome on Mac OS:

[image]

I've tried every workaround I can think of, but just cannot make the browsers display them consistently. It seems like a browser bug to me. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Here's a codepen which details the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpPpvG

Comment: add this to your css and test *{  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;}

Comment: Thank you @LuckyChingi, but that didn't seem to fix it unfortunately :(

Comment: Can I see the site online? or can you share on codepen?

Comment: Thanks so much for offering to help @LuckyChingi. I have a codepen here, and it's showing the same inconsistency: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpPpvG

Comment: @DaraJavaherian please try to use a normalizer https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ or a css resetter and http://cssreset.com/ tell us if it solved your problem

Comment: @DaraJavaherian try this last attempt, look here https://jsfiddle.net/Lzhb7653/ try to force the padding of your select tag, so maybe you are able to get a "fix" design among your platforms. Let me know if it works :) thanks

Comment: Thanks @GibboK, but that didn't work either :( I'm just going to give up and maybe file a bug report.

Comment: Yes, sound a good idea. If you have the change, please add ink to your bug report here on this question, as it could be usefully to other reader :)

Comment: Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=554951&thanks=554951&ts=1447341344

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying using a CSS `reset` or a `normalizer` in order to set a "common" settings for html element among different browsers and osx, as it usually here are tiny discrepancies among browsers and OSs.
I would also suggest you, generally, to test using the same fonts and font-size among your platform.

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

or

http://cssreset.com/

I would advice to use just one of these two in your project.

Comment: Unfortunately I have only a PC for testing right now, but let me know if my answer solves your problem thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Each browser will render select boxes differently.  If you are JS-savvy you can use a jQuery plugin to convert select boxes to HTML and CSS, and they will display consistently across all browsers.  Here is the plugin I typically use:

http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/

This will help to add colors, etc...whatever custom CSS you want.

Comment: Why downvote this? You upvote normalize.css, but downvote a jQuery plugin that eliminates the problem entirely.  This actually might be a better solution for some people that come to this page.